# sp_FuzzyLookupTableMaintenanceInstall not found while running SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis, oledb

I have an error while running a SSIS package:

DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB Error has ocurred.....
"Could not find stored procedure sys.sp_FuzzyLookupTableMaintenanceInstall"

I connect to to my db and I´m able to find the stored procedure.

sp_FuzzyLookupTableMaintenanceInstall
sys  assembly stored procedure  2008-11-24 14:23:08.930

I don´t know what it is happening.

I Have Installed:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      9.00.4035.00
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    2005.090.4035.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     2000.086.3959.00 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710)
Microsoft MSXML                 2.6 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer         6.0.3790.3959
Microsoft .NET Framework            2.0.50727.3082
Operating System                5.2.3790

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Worth a very quick check: Which edition of SQL Server is it running on? Fuzzy lookup one of the enterprise only feature I am thinking.

Comment: Enterprise Ed. Actually, I can run the package if I choose not to store the fuzzy index on the DB. The package fails if I do so. Permissions maybe?

Comment: You are probably on the right lines, you should grant the permission to run it by the account executing the package.

Comment: I changed the option to create and persist the fuzzy index, I have choose create and mantain, I think that is the error. I created the index, then I changed to reuse the index and now the package runs hell fast. This is what I wanted.

Thanks for your support.